# JCE deployed with project instead of JDK update

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, aes, jce

I'm trying to use BouncyCastle for AES encryption and have downloaded the latest JCE from Oracle and installed it locally on my Dev PC, all good.

However, I intend to deploy my code at work on customer servers and I can't see it being easy to get them to agree with numerous JDK lib/security updates. Security will never trump cost at our place (no matter what they tell us).

So my question is, using Eclipse and JDK 1.8.11 is it possible to package the JCE into my Jar/War files?

If so How?

I've read various links on SO and elsewhere. Most are quite old so I was wondering if in 2017 this was possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" with JCE, then you cannot achieve what you need with any kind of packaging. These policy files need to be installed to the running JVM, and thus you cannot solve this problem either programmatically or via different packaging options.

To achieve what you need, you have to use BC throgh their own API, rather then calling JCE functions and specifying "BC" as the provider since it will fail because of policy/security checks. You can walk around this check only by using BC API (or any other crypto library) directly.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected this but wanted to ask and find out for certain.